# Can I interact with the output of the OSX `say` command in a bash script?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have the following line that I run in terminal:

```
say "hello, this is the computer talking" --interactive
```

When I run this command, the computer speaks the words in quotes and highlights the words as they are spoken. What I would like to do is get the time of each spoken word. For example:

- 00.00 hello
- 01.23 this
- 01.78 is
- 02.10 the
- 02.70 computer
- 03.30 talking

I am wondering if there is any way to write a bash script that would interact with the output of the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Zsh script that almost does exactly what you want.

```
#!/bin/zsh
zmodload zsh/datetime
say --interactive "hello, this is the computer talking" | {
    counter=0
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\r' line; do
        (( counter++ )) || continue  # first line in the output of `say --interactive` suppresses the cursor; discard this line
        timestamp=$EPOCHREALTIME
        (( counter == 2 )) && offset=$timestamp  # set the timestamp of the actual first line at the offset
        (( timestamp -= offset ))
        printf '%05.2f %s\n' $timestamp ${${line%$'\e[m'*}#*$'\e[7m'}
    done
}
```

Sample output:

```
00.00 hello
00.26 ,
00.52 this
00.65 is
00.78 the
01.36 computer
02.04 talking
```

If you want to convert this to bash, then floating point arithmetic needs to be done in external commands like `bc`, and to get a precise timestamp you would need coreutils `date` (`timestamp=$(gdate +%s.%N)`).

By the way, if you don't want to see the comma, you can just filter it out.