# OSX Terminal Say Command --interactive timing

Tags: macos, bash, zsh

I had this question ([Can I interact with the output of the OSX `say` command in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768852/osx-terminal-say-command)) about determining the timing of the say command in OSX.

The solution above works great, but I was wondering if it would be possible to do this faster than real time (If I have a 15 minutes clip, I have to let the program run for 15 minutes).  I am wondering if it would be possible to analyze the resulting output.

Let me know if there are any idea.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to do it faster than real time using that method. What those solutions are doing is essentially counting the updates that occur when the interactive mode highlights a word and printing the word at that "index" along with the time relative to when the program started.

There is no way of doing what you are asking with the `say` command. There may be a way of querying the speech synthesizer, but the only with I see from a quick glance is the words per minute which is not going to be exact for an arbitrary string. If an estimate is good enough for you then you could use that.

What exactly are you trying to do? You can set the speaking rate of `say` by supplying the `-r` option (in words per minute) and when combined with a count of words (easily done with scripting) you can calculate a rough estimate of the time it will take.

Comment: I am trying to make some captions for an mp3 that I generated with the say command.  It would be useful if I didn't have to wait the entire time of the mp3 every time I make a small change.

Answer (score 0):

You could incrementally gather a data set of known word durations and use `say` only for words not already in the data set, adding the results to the set.